Angular 17 Prerender handle API errors
I have an Angular project version 17.2.1 and I started using Prerender for SSG loading. I don't find any document showing what happens if an Api request returns 500 or 504 or 400 or 499. I want to know if the Prerendered page will be created empty or the build process will fail. Or if I can handle each error.
